# Inconsistent behavior in awk

Tags: awk

I have a text file called `junk.txt`:

```
hello
foo
0
-1
0
1
0
2
0
foo

Cindy
00000

Lou
2 000
0
Who
0000
0
wat?
0000 00000
0
0
0000 00000

filler

00

0
00
000
0000
0

0
bye
```

When I run the following I get this:

```
cat junk.txt | awk '{if (/foo/ ~ $1) print $1,"<-- found match"; else print $1}'
awk: cmd. line:1: warning: regular expression on left of `~' or `!~' operator
hello
foo
0 <-- found match
-1
0 <-- found match
1
0 <-- found match
2
0 <-- found match
foo
 <-- found match
Cindy
00000
 <-- found match
Lou
2
0 <-- found match
Who
0000
0
wat?
0000
0
0
0000
 <-- found match
filler
 <-- found match
00
 <-- found match
0 <-- found match
00 <-- found match
000 <-- found match
0000 <-- found match
0 <-- found match
 <-- found match
0 <-- found match
bye
```

I understand what is happening when the regex is to the left of the `~`.

I understand that a `0` or an empty string (null?) will count as a match.

What I do not understand is why sometimes a `0` will match, and sometimes it won't.  It seems like it has something to do with whatever record was processed before it, but I thought `awk` treated each input record independently so they shouldn't affect one another (at least not without some variable assignments or other manipulation).

EDIT: In case it matters I'm using GNU Awk 4.1.3

Answer (score 4):

From (g)awks man page:

```
~ !~        Regular expression match, negated match.  NOTE: Do not use a constant regular  expression  (/foo/)
            on  the left-hand side of a ~ or !~.  Only use one on the right-hand side.  The expression /foo/ ~
            exp has the same meaning as (($0 ~ /foo/) ~ exp).  This is usually not what you want.
```

What do you expect to happen if you use it in a way it explicitly tells you not to?

Comment: As I said, I understand what is happening when you have a regex to the left of a ~.  I read the man page.  What I don't understand, and what my question was was why is it inconsistent.  Sometimes a `0` will match, sometimes it will not.  Sometimes `0000` will match, sometimes it won't.  Why?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, that's an interesting question. @tink pointed out why your code does not work as expected, but that wasn't the question. The question was "why does `0` sometimes match".

If `(/foo/ ~ $1)` really means `(($0 ~ /foo/) ~ $1)`, then `($0 ~ /foo/)` will evaluate to `1` if the line contains `foo` and `0` otherwise. Thus, you are (mostly) evaluating `0 ~ $1`. If the input line is empty, then `$1 == ""`, and an empty regular expression always matches. If the input line is exactly `0`, so is `$1`, and `0 ~ 0` is true. If the input line is `000`, for example, then so is `$1`, and `0 ~ 000` should not be true. However, it is likely that the `000` is converted to `0` before the match is checked.

But unfortunately, this explanation does not cover all cases.

**Case 1**

```
0 <-- found match
a
0 <-- found match
0 <-- found match
```

This is exactly as expected.

**Case 2**

```
0 <-- found match
00 00 <-- found match
0 <-- found match
```

This is also what is expected, provided that any number of zeros is interpreted as `0`. But now, this:

**Case 3**

```
0 <-- found match
a
00 0
0
```

This can not be explained away so simply. After a failed match, the conversion to zero does not seem to happen, and following lines that should match don't.

**Case 4**

```
0 <-- found match
a
00 00
a
0 <-- found match
```

Whatever happens, another failed match seems to reset `awk`'s behaviour to normal, and matching works as expected again.

To conclude, either the explanation from the GNU `awk` man page, which is not part of the info page, incidentally, is incorrect (or, at the very least, incomplete), or the program contains a bug.

Comment: "If the input line is 000, for example, then so is $1, and 0 ~ 000 is not true."

Then why does it match?

`000 <-- found match`

Comment: @Linoob You are correct. I have amended my answer.

Comment: Thanks for taking another look at it.  Seems like a bug to me, but since this isn't a normal use case I'm not going to worry about it.  I was just trying to understand `awk` a bit better.